# How do I change a model of a person to another model?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a model of a person in my project and I found another .obj file online. I imported it into the project and changed the name of that to the name of the original object. I also changed the name of the new material to the name of the old material. Then I deleted the original file and the object does not show up on the scene anymore. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated! P.s. I am using unity version 5.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity does not reference elements by their names. If you delete the referenced object then reference will be lost, unity will not lookup for another object with same name.

So, to display object_2 in place of object_1 you have to manually change the reference from object_1 to object_2 in the inspector. Or if object_1 is directly placed in the scene then simply delete the object_1 from scene and drag & drop object_2 from project to scene hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate your model in the *Project* tab and drag it to your `Hierarchy` tab[image: Example]